# Select specific rows and cells in text file and put into data frame: python or R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data.table

Either python or R is fine to use for this but could someone advise me on how to select the "Basic stats" rows a text file that looks like the one below. I want this information and the name of the ROI to be put in a pandas data frame  or as a data table in R.

```
ROI: mrc_ranch_house [Red] 195 points

Basic Stats        Min       Max         Mean      Stdev
     Band 1 -20.208261  6.025762    -8.866403   5.289712

Histogram           DN     Npts   Total  Percent     Acc Pct
Band 1      -20.208261        1       1   0.5128      0.5128
Bin=0.10287 -20.105383        0       1   0.0000      0.5128
            -20.002504        1       2   0.5128      1.0256
            -19.899626        0       2   0.0000      1.0256
            -19.796747        0       2   0.0000      1.0256
            -19.693869        0       2   0.0000      1.0256
            -19.590990        0       2   0.0000      1.0256
            -19.488112        0       2   0.0000      1.0256

Stats for ROI: river_1 [Blue] 90 points                     
Basic Stats        Min        Max         Mean     Stdev        
     Band 1 -20.187374  -6.694543   -12.227586  2.66464     

Histogram           DN     Npts   Total  Percent     Acc Pct    
Band 1      -20.187374  1   1   1.1111  1.1111  
Bin=0.05291 -20.134461  0   1   0   1.1111  
        -20.081548  0   1   0   1.1111  
        -20.028635  0   1   0   1.1111  
        -19.975722  0   1   0   1.1111  


Stats for ROI: river_2 [Blue] 96 points                 
Basic Stats        Min        Max         Mean     Stdev    
     Band 1 -18.365091  -5.820825   -13.164463  2.851231    

 Histogram              DN     Npts   Total  Percent     Acc Pct
 Band 1         -18.365091  1   1   1.0417  1.0417
 Bin=0.04919    -18.315898  0   1   0   1.0417
        -18.266705  0   1   0   1.0417
        -18.217512  0   1   0   1.0417
```

The final output should look something like this:

```
ROI              Min        Max         Mean        Stdev
mrc_ranch_house -20.208261  6.025762    -8.866403   5.289712
river_1         -20.187374  -6.694543   -12.227586  2.66464
river_2         -18.365091  -5.820825   -13.164463  2.851231
```

... etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `readLines` to read in the data line by line. Reading this untidy output will take some regex foo as well.

Comment: Is `readLines` in python? Thanks for the edits by the way.

Comment: This is a base function from R. See also `gsub`.

Comment: See [mcve]. You should make an example that is only as large as necessary to illustrate the problem; and you should make the example reproducible in the long-term (so embedded in the question, not provided through a link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With R, using:

```
# read the text file
txt <- readLines('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45095175/rois_all.txt')

# create an index for the lines that are needed
ti <- rep(which(grepl('ROI:', txt)), each = 3) + 1:3
# create a grouping vector of the same length
grp <- rep(1:33, each = 3)

# filter the text with the index 'ti' 
# and split into a list with grouping variable 'grp'
lst <- split(txt[ti], grp)
# loop over the list a read the text parts in as dataframes
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) read.table(text = x, sep = '\t', header = TRUE,
                                          blank.lines.skip = TRUE))

# bind the dataframes in the list together in one data.frame
DF <- do.call(rbind, lst)
# change the name of the first column
names(DF)[1] <- 'ROI'

# get the correct ROI's for the ROI-column
DF$ROI <- sub('.*: (\\w+).*$', '\\1', txt[grepl('ROI: ', txt)])
```

gives:

```
> DF
                ROI        Min        Max       Mean    Stdev
1   mrc_ranch_house -20.208261   6.025762  -8.866403 5.289712
2           river_1 -20.187374  -6.694543 -12.227586 2.664640
3           river_2 -18.365091  -5.820825 -13.164463 2.851231
4           river_3 -18.291010  -4.583666 -12.092995 3.479293
5           river_4 -17.074295  -4.926921  -9.970926 2.897855
6           river_5 -16.849176  -8.622208 -12.387085 2.168462
7  adjacent_river_2 -18.987597  -7.957749 -13.392523 1.962263
8  adjacent_river_3 -19.426531  -8.640042 -13.467425 1.888105
9  adjacent_river_4 -20.452566  -6.830183 -12.833450 2.124761
10           bcs_1_ -23.612043  -8.221417 -16.032305 2.080695
11           bcs_2_ -24.018219 -10.648975 -16.814048 1.948863
12           bcs_3_ -23.011086  -9.106754 -15.404174 1.867498
13           red_1_ -22.313442  -7.839107 -14.768196 2.134152
14           red_2_ -22.551537  -7.236300 -14.613618 2.204253
15           red_3_ -22.057703  -7.746992 -14.483161 2.123497
16            bcs_4 -22.705107  -8.972753 -15.201623 1.817122
17            bcs_5 -24.109459 -10.113716 -15.776537 1.849163
18         glade_1_ -19.913187  -6.189866 -12.695884 3.303929
19         glade_2_ -19.812855  -4.672865 -11.995191 4.840168
20         glade_3_ -10.078033  -2.828722  -5.877417 1.941401
21           mwea_b -13.979379  -4.977155 -11.392434 2.019037
22             kaga -13.114172  -8.889531 -10.649324 1.290551
23             huku -14.206743  -7.853305 -10.608210 1.441250
24             ruai -18.643108 -12.645180 -14.540123 1.224183
25          tumaini -19.543234 -13.164941 -15.899968 1.812876
26           nkando -19.973492  -7.040238 -11.716987 2.617544
27           jikaze -16.408030  -9.001065 -12.323898 1.942196
28        miarage_b -15.126486  -6.661448 -10.391111 1.764279
29           batian -15.269146  -9.603316 -11.962470 1.168859
30         gitaraga -17.037708  -7.495215 -10.886802 2.561877
31       wiumiririe  -9.578024  -6.225223  -7.688715 1.059796
32           chumvi -14.883148 -10.327570 -12.819469 1.231636
33 next_to_airstrip -17.242777  -5.207252 -10.601750 1.987712
```

---

The last part (from binding the list together in one dataframe and onwards) can also be done with the `rbindlist`-function from the `data.table`-package:

```
# load the 'data.table' package for the 'rbindlist' function
library(data.table)
# bind the dataframes in the list together to a data.table (enhanced version of a data.frame)
DT <- rbindlist(lst)
# change the name of the first column
setnames(DT, 1, 'ROI')

# get the correct ROI's for the ROI-column
DT[, ROI := sub('.*: (\\w+).*$', '\\1', txt[grepl('ROI: ', txt)])]
```

Comment: Gah, beat me to it but due to https://twitter.com/romunov/status/836622674944266240

Comment: Hey @Jaap! I am wondering if you could help me with this simple question: I now have a text file with multiple `Bands` but haven't been been able to get your code to work. Can you check it out here, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614688/broken-r-code-to-select-specific-rows-and-cells-in-text-file-and-put-into-data-f?noredirect=1#comment72359303_42614688

Comment: @JAG2024 seen & answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another ugly solution. The result is a good old regular `data.frame`.

```
rois_all <- file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45095175/rois_all.txt")

xy <- readLines(rois_all)

# find lines where ROI starts
roin <- grep(pattern = "ROI: ", x = xy)
roi <- xy[roin]
roi <- gsub(".*ROI: (\\w+).*$", "\\1", roi)

# find lines with stats
stats <- grep(pattern = "Basic Stats", x = xy)

# trim whitespace and collect Col
cn <- trimws(sapply(strsplit(xy[stats][1], "\t"), "[", 2:5, simplify = FALSE)[[1]])

# split the stat line by \t and extract only elements 2 to 5. merge row-wise
out <- do.call(rbind, sapply(strsplit(xy[stats + 1], "\t"), "[", 2:5, simplify = FALSE))
out <- as.data.frame(apply(out, MARGIN = 2, as.numeric))

# add ROI column extracted earlier
out <- cbind(roi, out)

colnames(out) <- c("ROI", cn)

out

                ROI        Min        Max       Mean    Stdev
1   mrc_ranch_house -20.208261   6.025762  -8.866403 5.289712
2           river_1 -20.187374  -6.694543 -12.227586 2.664640
3           river_2 -18.365091  -5.820825 -13.164463 2.851231
4           river_3 -18.291010  -4.583666 -12.092995 3.479293
5           river_4 -17.074295  -4.926921  -9.970926 2.897855
6           river_5 -16.849176  -8.622208 -12.387085 2.168462
7  adjacent_river_2 -18.987597  -7.957749 -13.392523 1.962263
8  adjacent_river_3 -19.426531  -8.640042 -13.467425 1.888105
9  adjacent_river_4 -20.452566  -6.830183 -12.833450 2.124761
10           bcs_1_ -23.612043  -8.221417 -16.032305 2.080695
11           bcs_2_ -24.018219 -10.648975 -16.814048 1.948863
12           bcs_3_ -23.011086  -9.106754 -15.404174 1.867498
13           red_1_ -22.313442  -7.839107 -14.768196 2.134152
14           red_2_ -22.551537  -7.236300 -14.613618 2.204253
15           red_3_ -22.057703  -7.746992 -14.483161 2.123497
16            bcs_4 -22.705107  -8.972753 -15.201623 1.817122
17            bcs_5 -24.109459 -10.113716 -15.776537 1.849163
18         glade_1_ -19.913187  -6.189866 -12.695884 3.303929
19         glade_2_ -19.812855  -4.672865 -11.995191 4.840168
20         glade_3_ -10.078033  -2.828722  -5.877417 1.941401
21           mwea_b -13.979379  -4.977155 -11.392434 2.019037
22             kaga -13.114172  -8.889531 -10.649324 1.290551
23             huku -14.206743  -7.853305 -10.608210 1.441250
24             ruai -18.643108 -12.645180 -14.540123 1.224183
25          tumaini -19.543234 -13.164941 -15.899968 1.812876
26           nkando -19.973492  -7.040238 -11.716987 2.617544
27           jikaze -16.408030  -9.001065 -12.323898 1.942196
28        miarage_b -15.126486  -6.661448 -10.391111 1.764279
29           batian -15.269146  -9.603316 -11.962470 1.168859
30         gitaraga -17.037708  -7.495215 -10.886802 2.561877
31       wiumiririe  -9.578024  -6.225223  -7.688715 1.059796
32           chumvi -14.883148 -10.327570 -12.819469 1.231636
33 next_to_airstrip -17.242777  -5.207252 -10.601750 1.987712
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman Luštrik. This code is very clear. I now have a text file with multiple bands and am trying to make it work, but currently am failing. Could you give it a look please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614688/broken-r-code-to-select-specific-rows-and-cells-in-text-file-and-put-into-data-f?noredirect=1#comment72359303_42614688

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a single import solution as each row in `data` is called `Band 1` but it is a good start.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'rois_all.txt', delimiter='\t', error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=[0, 1])
data = data.dropna()
data = data.ix[data.ix[:, 'Basic Stats']!='Basic Stats', :]
data
```

Example of output

```
Basic Stats Min         Max         Mean        Stdev
0   Band 1  -20.208261  6.025762    -8.866403   5.289712
3   Band 1  -20.187374  -6.694543   -12.227586  2.664640
6   Band 1  -18.365091  -5.820825   -13.164463  2.851231
```

I have now extracted all of the Basic Stats names as follows,

```
names = pd.read_csv(r'rois_all.txt', delimiter='\t', error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=[0, 1])

names = names.ix[names.ix[:, 'Basic Stats'] != '     Band 1']
names = names.ix[names.ix[:, 'Basic Stats'] != 'Basic Stats']
names = names.ix[:, 'Basic Stats'].str.extract('Stats for ROI: (.*) \[.*\] [0-9]*')
names.loc[0] = 'mrc_ranch_house'
names = names.sort_index()
names = names.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This looks as follows,

```
0      mrc_ranch_house
1              river_1
2              river_2
```

Joining `data` and `names` like so,

```
data.ix[:, 'Basic Stats'] = names
```

gives this the results as desired,

```
   Basic Stats      Min         Max         Mean        Stdev
0   mrc_ranch_house -20.208261  6.025762    -8.866403   5.289712
1   river_1         -20.187374  -6.694543   -12.227586  2.664640
2   river_2         -18.365091  -5.820825   -13.164463  2.851231
```

Comment: Could you add the part for how to select the name of the ROI and add this info into a column?

Comment: This is not the full solution.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I said as much in my answer. I had that part of the solution and though it was more use to JAG2024 than not posting anything.

Comment: Fair enough for me.